# Type theory for imperative programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

The type theory that I have seen is all developed over lambda calculus, which is an inherently functional language.

Nevertheless, in practice imperative languages have type systems. Are there differences in the type **theory** for imperative vs functional languages?

Comment: Why is the lambda calculus "inherently functional"? You can easily add mutable state to a lambda calculus (which is basically what SML and O'Caml do), and you have a higher-order imperative programming language. It's not hard to encode the lambda calculus into most object oriented programming languages (even ones without lambdas themselves, e.g. earlier Java) essentially via the Strategy Pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Sure there are type systems for all sorts of programming languages, including the imperative ones. It's probably best to look at something simple first that exposes the gist of the matter. A classic is John Reynold's [The essence of algol](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Reynolds81.ps), which was quite influential historically, and develops many important ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at chapters 13 and 19 of [Types and Programing Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) that handle types for constructs with side-effects, and a more general imperative language (Java) respectively.

As Andrej says, the type system community is aware of imperative languages (indeed, I know of very few completely pure systems!), and theory has developed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much, but I am pretty sure [Linear Type Theory](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/linear+type+theory) is used to model imperative programs. For example, [Adoption and focus: practical linear types for imperative programming](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/543552.512532) or [On linear types and imperative update](https://surface.syr.edu/eecs_etd/273/). [Rust](https://groups.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs152/2016sp/lectures/lec17-substructural.pdf), for example, is built on something related to linear types (I forget what exactly though).

It appears the more general category of type systems is [Substructural type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system). [Here](https://wiki.zhen-zhang.com/tech/notes/books/AT-TAPL/Substructural%20Types/) is some more good info on that.